# What is happening that it prints extra output apart from garbage when I change the code below?

Tags: gcc

I understand that the below code prints garbage value when run in windows OS and I tried changing source code and it prints extra hello world that is not coded to be printed extra time somewhere else

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // array to print and extra one
    char text[12] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0'};
    char other[12];

    // commands to execute in terminal and clear screen
    char clear[] = "cls";
    char sleep[] = "python -c \"from time import sleep; sleep(0.05)\"";

    // logic to output hello world
    char line[] = "--------------------";
    char spaces[] = "                    ";
    int start = 97;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if ((char)(start + j) == text[i])
            {
                other[i] = (char)(start + j);
                printf("%s\n", line);
                printf("%s\n", spaces);
                printf("%s\n", spaces);

                printf("%s %s\r", spaces, spaces);
                printf("%s\n", other);

                printf("%s\n", spaces);
                printf("%s\n", spaces);
                printf("%s\n", line);

                system(sleep);
                system(clear);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (' ' == text[i])
                {
                    other[i] = ' ';
                    printf("%s\n", line);
                    printf("%s\n", spaces);
                    printf("%s\n", spaces);

                    printf("%s %s\r", spaces, spaces);
                    printf("%s\n", other);

                    printf("%s\n", spaces);
                    printf("%s\n", spaces);
                    printf("%s\n", line);

                    system(sleep);
                    system(clear);
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    if ('\0' == text[i])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        other[i] = (char)(start + j);
                        printf("%s\n", line);
                        printf("%s\n", spaces);
                        printf("%s\n", spaces);

                        printf("%s %s\r", spaces, spaces);
                        printf("%s\n", other);

                        printf("%s\n", spaces);
                        printf("%s\n", spaces);
                        printf("%s\n", line);

                        system(sleep);
                        system(clear);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", line);
    printf("%s\n", spaces);
    printf("%s\n", spaces);

    printf("%s %s\r", spaces, spaces);
    printf("%s\n", other);

    printf("%s\n", spaces);
    printf("%s\n", spaces);
    printf("%s\n", line);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing
char other[12];
to
char other[12] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};

and I expected it to remove garbage value in output and it started printing extra hello world there